# How do I check for a dying cable modem without a known working one?

Tags: modem, cable-modem

That pretty much sums it up. Have to rule out a finicky modem as the cause of my bandwidth issues, but I'm not geeky enough (read ***too cheap***) to keep an extra modem in my spare parts box. I'm pretty sure everything behind it is fine, as I've tested traffic at the firewall and everything is still lagging.

[This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004XC6GJ0) is the model in case anyone's curious, Motorola Surfboard 6121. I highly doubt it's dying but I must appease the ISP. I'm currently searching for the possibility of a firmware update, but the thing doesn't even have an IP on my network which might complicate matters.

Comment: If your modem is directly connected to your computer (either via wire or via wireless), you can use your default gateway IP to connect to the modem. Else you'll have to connect to the intermediate device and find the gateway there. I know it won't fix your issue itself, but at least you can try and do some diagnostics that way.

Comment: Most Motorola modems use the IP `192.168.100.1`.

Comment: While the Motorola Surfboard 6121 isn't a cheap modem its extremely senistive to a bad signal. The first thing you need to do is make sure your ISP pushes their most recent iirmware to it. **YOU CANNOT DO THIS YOURSELF** In order to determine if that needs to be done, I would need to know what the current firmware is, so I can compare it to the one I have. It actually does have an IP on your network.  It depends what sort of bandwidth issues your experience.  That specific model is sort of old, most major markets, have already advanced beyond that model.